# Is magic possible?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, decision-problem, matrix

A [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) is an **n-by-n** square grid, filled with distinct positive integers in the range **1,2,...n^2**, such that each cell contains a different integer and the sum of the integers in each row, column and diagonal is equal.

Your task is to take an **n-by-n** matrix consisting of positive numbers, and a placeholder character for empty cells (I'll use **0**, but you can use any non-numeric character or datatype you like), and determine if it's possible to make a magic square by filling in the missing numbers

The matrix will be at least **2-by-2**, and at most **10-by-10**. The smallest possible non-trivial magic square is **3-by-3**. The numbers in the input matrix might be higher than **n^2**, and it's possible that all cells are filled.

### Test cases:

```
2   2
2   0
False

8   0   6
0   5   0
0   9   2
True

16    2    3   13
 5   11   10    8
 9    7    6   12
 4   14   15    1
True

10   0   1
 0   5   9
 3   7   5
False

99    40    74     8    15    51     0    67     0     1
 0    41    55    14     0    57    64     0    98     0
81    47    56    20    22    63    70    54     0    88
 0    28     0    21     0    69    71    60    85    19
 0    34     0     2     9    75    52    61     0    25
24    65    49     0    90    26    33    42    17    76
 0     0    30    89    91     0    39    48     0    82
 6    72    31    95     0    38    45    29     0    13
12    53     0    96    78     0     0     0    10    94
18    59    43    77     0     0    27    36     0   100
True
```

Comment: Hmm. I think I've seen a solution somewhere..

Comment: Suggested test case to make sure that the diagonals are tested correctly: `[ [ 1, 5, 9 ], [ 6, 7, 2 ], [ 8, 3, 4 ] ]` (falsy)

Comment: Can we number the placeholders (i.e. `[[8, X1, 6], [X2, 5, X3], [X4, 9, 2]]`)?

Comment: @Scott sure, feel free...

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>270</s> 268 bytes

Takes the matrix as a 2D array. Returns `0` or `1`.

```js
a=>(g=(x,y=0,w=a.length,p,R=a[y])=>[0,1,2,3].some(d=>a.some((r,y)=>(p=s)^(s=r.reduce((p,v,x)=>(o|=1<<(v=[v,(b=a[x])[y],b[x++],b[w-x]][d]),p+v),0))&&p),s=o=0)||o/2+1!=1<<w*w?R&&[...Array(w*w)].map((_,n)=>(p=R[x])==++n|!p&&(R[x]=n,g(z=(x+1)%w,y+!z),R[x]=p)):r=1)(r=0)&&r
```

#### Test cases

This is definitely too slow for the last test case. :-(

```js
let f =

a=>(g=(x,y=0,w=a.length,p,R=a[y])=>[0,1,2,3].some(d=>a.some((r,y)=>(p=s)^(s=r.reduce((p,v,x)=>(o|=1<<(v=[v,(b=a[x])[y],b[x++],b[w-x]][d]),p+v),0))&&p),s=o=0)||o/2+1!=1<<w*w?R&&[...Array(w*w)].map((_,n)=>(p=R[x])==++n|!p&&(R[x]=n,g(z=(x+1)%w,y+!z),R[x]=p)):r=1)(r=0)&&r

console.log(f([
  [ 2,  2 ],
  [ 2,  0 ]
]));

console.log(f([
  [ 8,  0,  6 ],
  [ 0,  5,  0 ],
  [ 0,  9,  2 ]
]));

console.log(f([
  [ 16,   2,   3,  13 ],
  [  5,  11,  10,   8 ],
  [  9,   7,   6,  12 ],
  [  4,  14,  15,   1 ]
]));

console.log(f([
  [ 10,  0,  1 ],
  [  0,  5,  9 ],
  [  3,  7,  5 ]
]));
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>45</s> 38 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
gn¹à@¹˜āsKœ0ªεÎ˜r.;¹gôD©ø®Å\®Å/)O˜Ë}à*
```

Also uses \$0\$ as placeholder. The more \$0\$s in the input, the slower the program is. Size of the matrix doesn't matter that much (a 10x10 matrix with three \$0\$s runs quite a bit faster than a 3x3 matrix with seven \$0\$s).

Could have been 4 bytes less, but there is currently a bug in the builtin `.;` with 2D lists. `:` and `.:` work as expected, but `.;` doesn't do anything on 2D lists right now.. hence the work-around of `˜` and `¹gô` to flatten the matrix; use `.;` on the list; and transform it back into a matrix again.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##FY8hT0RBDIR/D@QLbNvd7ttgEDgEP@A4AQkhGEg4jUCgSDDYE2dBoCDh7FtQl/CXHn1JUzEznZnerS4ub66m6fp23PbN8bjdrX8eV6e/r2l8//vqL7v1/cHRuL3unyfjW/8eP/rT@bwO98526/780Df707RYmFAdMcwZBBnQRs2ILFmokhMlsEouuKEJGygepAdGDrHSSHgh1DUIS9SCKKbUimQsUxsyX6lgjVJRIwuloYVs@JznTqADHhGUsImhaDCJISFxNVANiRYWmVJmRydnXJGGhTx6RC/FU5BVCK@wj4/IjjecIsvlPw) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##dZG9SgRBEIRf5bhMKXS6528HAw0uMzASDtYLFERMFBQEAwMDTcw0NTDVwEjB@FYjwYfwRc7q2VMQFJbd2Z7pqq96Do@3d/Z3Zyenq8PB5@X1YLh6Otqc7R2Mu7u18fvt6/nx@tuNmz58PDv@Hi2tjPe6p9H0vnuZPnYXW/ZaXth4v@2uzrq7xRlmbdsqdAK@3WSCQds2cEgsOESW7Ft4oG5JgsJDPMsRIhCHhuuCjAQxmQDhw82fDvd/h/ujwbFB5vaFX8@Tsd@zLfeLzH1D0yKbUGBZlNKFZlw3ZijUsHpkn0LS3MmbUwPNxqW9YECNW@pIKKRiqkp5Ro@GY3EiPOcQetUMTdWlWIxvLqUzMbyf8wlyMhCf0Ei15QhCD6mKwEwVJUQkTxr4BtGuIbGGwMNKMN6MRQi5J8kcmxpLruGNqFg@Sgp8QcyGHgSRgSKCRzK/RC6EBokWiJRxNmOt5I2zSZI@ewvl65AsOEOGgKSW0/M4OcjFUVviLKAW5ZkIISEVZo@80skX). (NOTE: Last test case of the challenge description is not included, because it has way too many 0s..)

**Explanation:**

```python
g          # Get the length of the (implicit) input-matrix (amount of rows)
           #  i.e. [[8,0,6],[0,5,0],[0,0,2]] → 3
 n         # Square it
           #  → 9
  ¹        # Push the input-matrix again
   à       # Pop and push its flattened maximum
           #  → 8
    @      # Check if the squared matrix-dimension is >= this maximum
           #  → 9 => 8 → 1 (truthy)
¹          # Push the input-matrix again
 ˜         # Flatten it
           #  → [8,0,6,0,5,0,0,0,2]
  ā        # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
           #  → [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
   s       # Swap so the flattened input is at the top of the stack again
    K      # Remove all these numbers from the ranged list
           #  → [1,3,4,7,9]
œ          # Get all possible permutations of the remaining numbers
           # (this part is the main bottleneck of the program;
           #  the more 0s and too high numbers, the more permutations)
           #   i.e. [1,3,4,7,9] → [[1,3,4,7,9],[1,3,4,9,7],...,[9,7,4,1,3],[9,7,4,3,1]]
 0ª        # Add an item 0 to the list (workaround for inputs without any 0s)
           #  i.e. [[1,3,4,7,9],[1,3,4,9,7],...,[9,7,4,1,3],[9,7,4,3,1]] 
           #   → [[1,3,4,7,9],[1,3,4,9,7],...,[9,7,4,1,3],[9,7,4,3,1],"0"] 
ε          # Map each permutation to:
 Î         #  Push 0 and the input-matrix
  ˜        #  Flatten the matrix again
   r       #  Reverse the items on the stack, so the order is [flat_input, 0, curr_perm]
    .;     #  Replace all 0s with the numbers in the permutation one by one
           #   i.e. [8,0,6,0,5,0,0,0,2] and [1,3,4,7,9]
           #    → [8,1,6,3,5,4,7,9,2]
      ¹g   #  Push the input-dimension again
        ô  #  And split the flattened list into parts of that size,
           #  basically transforming it back into a matrix
           #   i.e. [8,1,6,3,5,4,7,9,2] and 3 → [[8,1,6],[3,5,4],[7,9,2]]
 D         #  Duplicate the current matrix with all 0s filled in
  ©        #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
   ø       #  Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns of the top matrix
           #   → [[8,3,7],[1,5,9],[6,4,2]]
 ®Å\       #  Get the top-left to bottom-right main diagonal of `®`
           #   i.e. [[8,1,6],[3,5,4],[7,9,2]] → [8,5,2]
 ®Å/       #  Get the top-right to bottom-left main diagonal of `®`
           #   i.e. [[8,1,6],[3,5,4],[7,9,2]] → [6,5,7]
    )      #  Wrap everything on the stack into a list
           #   → [[[8,1,6],[3,5,4],[7,9,2]],
           #      [[8,3,7],[1,5,9],[6,4,2]],
           #      [8,5,2],
           #      [6,5,7]]
     O     #  Sum each inner list
           #   → [[15,12,18],[18,15,12],15,18]
      ˜    #  Flatten it
           #   → [15,12,18,18,15,12,15,18]
       Ë   #  Check if all values are the same
           #   → 0 (falsey)
}à         # After the map: Check if any are truthy by taking the maximum
           #  → 1 (truthy)
*          # And multiply it to the check we did at the start to verify both are truthy
           #  → 1 (truthy)
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

The part `D©ø®Å\®Å/)O˜Ë` is also used in [my 05AB1E answer for the *Verify Magic Square* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178959/52210), so see that answer for a more in-depth explanation about that part of the code.